# Problems with Backbone.js inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I believed I had a good background in backbone.js but I have a problem I don't understand.

Suppose we have these two views:

```
BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({

    foo: {},

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        // ...
    }
});

PageView = BaseView.extend({

    render: function() {
        this.foo.bar = 23;
    }
});
```

If we check the attribute 'foo' in both views, obviously, it will be an empty object:

```
> BaseView.prototype.foo
  Object {}
> PageView.prototype.foo
  Object {}
```

But if we create a PageView instance, the 'foo' attribute from BaseView will be changed. How is that possible?

```
> page = new PageView()
> page.foo
  Object {foo: 23}
> BaseView.prototype.foo
  Object {foo: 23}
```

**[Edit]**

Actually, it's a general OOP question. In python:

```
class A(object):
    foo = {}

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo['bar'] = 23

>>> print A.foo
{}
>>> b = B()
>>> print A.foo
{'bar': 23}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    foo: {},
    //...
});
```

That `foo: { }` gets attached to the `BaseView` prototype. That means that that exact object is shared by all instances of `BaseView` and by all instances of any `BaseView` "subclasses". So given this:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    foo: {},
    //...
});
var PageView = BaseView.extend({
    //...
});
var bv = new BaseView;
var pv = new PageView;
```

the data really looks like this:

```
bv.foo -->--+-->-- BaseView.prototype.foo -->-- { }
            |
pv.foo -->--/
```

so if you alter `pv.foo` with something like `pv.foo.x = y`, you're actually altering `BaseView.prototype.foo` and that's the same object as `bv.foo`; of course if you `pv.foo = something_else` then you've changed the reference and `bv.foo` and `pv.foo` will no longer refer to the same underlying object. You have only one underlying object with multiple references to it.

There is no copying (neither shallow nor deep) when you instantiate or extend your `BaseView` or `PageView`, you're just sharing a single reference to the underlying object.

If you want your `foo` to be instance-specific (as you almost always do), then set it up in your constructor:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.foo = { };
        //...
    },
    //...
});
```

Of course, the `initialize` methods don't chain by themselves so you'll have to do that yourself if your `PageView` needs one:

```
var PageView = BaseView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        BaseView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        // Whatever else you need done...
    },
    //...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4duQ5/

---

Also, you really should be saying `var BaseView` rather than just `BaseView`, no `var` means that you're creating a global and you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: *so if you alter `pv.foo`, you're actually altering BaseView.prototype.foo* that's not entirely true (just language matters I'd say). If he alters the object referenced by `pv.foo`, yeah, the prototype will change. But if he gives him another value, it'll just shadow the prototype. I think that's a point worth to specify.

Comment: @Loamhoof: Good point, I guess I think of "alter `pv.foo`" to mean something like `pv.foo.x = y` rather than `pv.foo = x` and I've internalized all the pointer semantics to the point that it can be difficult to explain. Is the updated version clearer?

Comment: @mu is too short: Thank you for point out that _there is no copying (neither shallow nor deep) when you instantiate_, that solve my doubt. However, I think that's not always true. For example, you can modify your `foo` attribute if is not an object (http://jsfiddle.net/7Ndf7/). I'm not using `var` because this I'm working with requirejs and in this case I need to create PageView as a global in order to extend it in another file. Also, you can use a `super` method to chain the initialise (https://gist.github.com/maxbrunsfeld/1542120)

Comment: @mastortosa: (1) But that's not changing the `foo` object itself, that is replacing the reference completely. (2) I'm sure require.js has a proper way to handle that situation without globals, half the point of require.js is to manage dependencies after all. (3) That `super` implementation is not stock Backbone, adding yet another library for an aside would just confuse things.

Comment: @mastortosa: Also, numbers for things like `foo` are fine and safe as there are no mutator methods for numbers in JavaScript; strings are similarly safe (unless my memory fails me and there are mutators for strings in JavaScript).

Comment: @mu is too short: 1) That's exactly what I need, I need foo = {bar: 23} only in PageView instances (and 'subclasses' instances) (http://jsfiddle.net/Hn6NC/). 2) In this case, is not a problem defining global views inside each files, I'm gonna add the files I need and I think is the only (or the best) way to access to a var definied in a file from another file. 3) The `super` method is not a backbone built-in method, but is really useful. Thank you!

Comment: Saying `this.foo.bar = 23;` still modifies the prototype's version, you'll have to `this.foo = _({}).extend(this.foo, { bar: 23 })` or similar if you just want to replace a single property of `foo`. I think you should read the require.js docs, there's no way that globals are necessary for what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or if I want to redefine `this.foo` without modify the prototype, `this.foo = {bar: 23}`.

Comment: ... about require. I can return a value in every file and define a variable name in each `define` function but I don't want to do that.